# Issue with 'gem install sqlite3-ruby' on RHEL6

Tags: ruby, sqlite, rubygems, rhel, sqlite3-ruby

I'm attempting to install Ruby on Rails 3 on RHEL 6.  I've 'yum install' sqlite and sqlite-devel (which is sqlite3 on RHEL6).  As you can see, sqlite3.h does exist where it needs to be.  'gem install sqlite3-ruby' still doesn't work, for some reason.

SQLite3:

```
[root@rhel6base gems]# yum list sqlite-devel
Installed Packages
sqlite-devel.x86_64            3.6.20-1.el6            @local
Available Packages
sqlite-devel.i686              3.6.20-1.el6            local 

[root@rhel6base gems]# ls -l /usr/include/sqlite3.h
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root 268966 Nov 24  2009 /usr/include/sqlite3.h
```

Gem install:

```
[root@rhel6base gems]# gem install sqlite3-ruby
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing sqlite3-ruby:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

        /usr/bin/ruby extconf.rb
checking for sqlite3.h... no
sqlite3.h is missing. Try 'port install sqlite3 +universal'
or 'yum install sqlite3-devel' and check your shared library search path (the
location where your sqlite3 shared library is located).
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of
necessary libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more
details.  You may need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
    --with-opt-dir
    --without-opt-dir
    --with-opt-include
    --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
    --with-opt-lib
    --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
    --with-make-prog
    --without-make-prog
    --srcdir=.
    --curdir
    --ruby=/usr/bin/ruby
    --with-sqlite3-dir
    --without-sqlite3-dir
    --with-sqlite3-include
    --without-sqlite3-include=${sqlite3-dir}/include
    --with-sqlite3-lib
    --without-sqlite3-lib=${sqlite3-dir}/lib


Gem files will remain installed in /usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/sqlite3-1.3.3 for inspection.
Results logged to /usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/sqlite3-1.3.3/ext/sqlite3/gem_make.out
```

PS: It'd sure be nice to create a 'rhel6' tag, but I don't have enough reputation.

Comment: Can you put outputs of these commands: # cat /usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/sqlite3-1.3.3/ext/sqlite3/gem_make.out and # uname -a

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It turns out you have to have gcc installed for 'gem install sqlite3-ruby' to work.  It will never explicitly tell you that gcc isn't found (even the log file doesn't mention it).

Comment: I recommend to do yum groupinstall "Development Tools" to install other valuable packages.

Answer (score 1):

> I've 'yum install' sqlite and
>   sqlite-devel (which is sqlite3 on
>   RHEL6)

That's not true. From my RHEL6 server installation:

```
# yum search sqlite
...
sqlite.i686 : Library that implements an embeddable SQL database engine
sqlite-devel.i686 : Development tools for the sqlite3 embeddable SQL database engine
...
```

You are missing sqlite3.h file. If you need a file that should be in RHEL6 repositories always use this command to find it:

```
# yum provides /usr/include/sqlite3.h
sqlite-devel-3.6.20-1.el6.i686 : Development tools for the sqlite3 embeddable SQL database engine
Repo        : rhel-i386-server-6.0.z
Matched from:
Filename    : /usr/include/sqlite3.h
```

Therefore **install sqlite-devel** package and you will be able to compile successfuly. Good luck.

Comment: It is true.  The '/usr/include/sqlite3.h' file is there.  'sqlite' and 'sqlite-devel' are both installed packages.  I show the existence of the sqlite3.h header file as the first line of the question.

Comment: 'sqlite' is the 'sqlite3' version of sqlite for RHEL6 - there is no pre-3 version, like there is for Ubuntu and other platforms (that I can find at least).

Comment: Well sqlite-devel IS NOT sqlite3 on RHEL6. That's simply not true. These are two separate packages with different files in it. I dont argue you did install both packages.

Comment: By the way I suspect the architecture. On the example above I can see you have i686 yum repo but installed version is x86_64. You must not mix different architectures. It wont compile. Make sure you have the correct arch (uname -a and then install the correct packages).

Comment: The issue was gcc wasn't installed.
I don't see anything for non-sqlite3 sqlite packaging.  'sqlite-devel' and 'sqlite' both install the '3.6.20' versions of their respective files, which *IS* sqlite3.   'yum info sqlite' and 'yum info sqlite3' will show that.